# C# Net Core Compare 2 List with Linq and Create New One

Tags: c#, api, linq, asp.net-core

I'm using .NET Core 6, SQL Server and Oracle databases. I created 2 object type generic lists. All lists contains same kind information.

Line, MaterialName, MaterialId and MaterialCount information and I don't have id information. I'm unable to join

```
var productList = new List<object>(); // **used elements**
var reportList = new List<object>();  // **must be used elements**
```

I have 4 lines and 20 materials. `reportList` has 40 elements, `productList` has 21.

I need to calculate percentile of materials. I need to proportion the materials used in an assembly line to the materials used as a percentage. The example below should use 2500 motherboards, but it looks like 2000 was used. So 100 * 2000 / 2500 = 80. So the efficiency is 80%.

Examples:

```
  reportList element                                     productList element

  {                                                      {
    "materialId": 1,                                            "materialId": 1,
    "line": "Line1",                                            "line": "Line1",
    "materialName": "Mainboard",                                "materialName": "Mainboard",
    "materialCount": 2500                                       "materialCount": 2000
  },                                                      },
```

Final list element have to be:

```
{  
    "materialId": 1,
    "line": "Line1",
    "materialName": "Mainboard",
    "materialCount": 80
},
```

If a product has never been used, it will not be registered in the `productlist`. The percentage number will automatically be 0.(So materialCount must be 0. materialCount = 0). So final list elements count will be same with reportList.

What doesn't work? They are simple generic lists. After "." symbol, we can't use any information because they are list. I can't type something is equal to something. We need something different...

```
*from report in reportList

join product in productList
on report.Line equals generalRule.Line*
```

Comment: Are you using Linq to objects (IEnumerable), or Linq to SQL (IQueryable)? Can there be two elements with the same materialId, but different MaterialName? Can there be two elements with the same materialId, but different line?

Comment: Your known type may be `List<object>` but it must contain some actual class to have the information you listed. What is the source of the `List<object>` and what is the actual type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you are using Linq to objects, you can use the [moreLinq library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)

It has a `LeftJoin` extension method.

```
class Element
{
    public int materialId { get; set; }
    public string line { get; set; }
    public string materialName { get; set; }
    public double materialCount { get; set; } // Must be double here for the calculation to work
}
```

```
var productList = new List<Element>(); // **used elements**
var reportList = new List<Element>();  // **must be used elements**

var result = reportList
    .LeftJoin(
        productList,
        // Join by materialId, line and materialName
        r => new { materialId = r.materialId, line = r.line, materialName = r.materialName },
        // No element in productList found, materialCount will be 0
        r => new Element {materialId = r.materialId, line = r.line, materialName = r.materialName }, 
        // An element in productList was found => do the calculation
        (r, p) => new Element {materialId = r.materialId, line = r.line, materialName = r.materialName, materialCount = 100 * p.materialCount / r.materialCount });
```

Comment: I tried but it is unable to find all r.materialId ,r.line, r.materialName etc... I created an entity and installed moreLinq extension.-------


Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'line' and no accessible extension method 'line' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @BurakİbrahimÜnal I think that wertzui is intending for you to use `var productList = new List<Element>()` instead of `var productList = new List<object>()`, and similarly for `reportList`. You may have a better name than "Element", but naming classes and variables is one of the hard problems in computer programing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton is correct, I edited the answer to include the definition of the lists.